# Loading addition org files along with default scratch buffer

Tags: init-file, files, start-up

I do a lot of my programming in Haskell and Python. I've started maintaining a personal cheat-sheet for each of these languages for common constructs and tasks I often come across.

Hence whenever I start an emacs process, in addition to the scratch buffer how do I load my files HaskellCheatSheet.org and PythonCheatSheet.org everytime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place two lines at the bottom of your `.emacs` file using `find-file` and adjust the path to the file locations.  If you want them loaded in the background only, then use `find-file-noselect` instead of `find-file` -- that way, they will not interfere with your current display window/buffer screen setup at startup.

```lisp
(find-file "/path/to/HaskellCheatSheet.org")

(find-file "/path/to/PythonCheatSheet.org")
```