# Open multiple files in different tabs when starting emacs

Tags: elscreen

I'm using Emacs on Windows. I plan on making a shortcut to Emacs for quick access.

However, I have 3 files that should always be opened when I start emacs (ideally in 3 separate tabs), and I want that to happen I click on the shortcut.

I've installed elscreen to get a tab bar-like functionality, but I'm not quite sure how to automatically open those 3 files in separate tabs.

Anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: If you want tab-bar like functionality, then do not use `elscreen`.  Instead, use `tabbar.el`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs  `elscreen` is for preserving window layouts.  Once you install and configure `tabbar.el`, all you need to do is have three (3) lines of code in your `.emacs` file using `find-file`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26985/2287  If you are interested in organizing buffers by frames, then see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame and also `frame-bufs`.

Comment: `elscreen`'s goal isn't to preserve window layouts, though [it's possible with another package](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen#Persistent_screens_accross_sessions), it's more to have tabs, but when we want, not for every file.

Comment: @Ehvince -- The link to the Emacs wiki describes `elscreen` as "**elscreen is a GNU Emacs window session manager modeled after GNU screen by NaotoMorishima.**":  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreenhttps://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen  I have `elscreen` installed, and can confirm that it is most definitely designed to manage window layouts within Emacs.

Comment: Yes ok, it does manage windows layout. I wanted to stress that it doesn't *persist* them by default (a goal of the question) and that it does *have tabs* (the doc says the window layouts are tabbed) even if tabs isn't the first goal of the app. It wanted to react to your "do not use elscreen", beause I think he can.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [elscreen-persist](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen#Persistent_screens_accross_sessions). Create screens and open the files you need, then call `M-x elscreen-persist-store` and `elscreen-persist-restore` to restore what you saved.

*and maybe tabbar.el does that through configuration.*